# Applying encryption on email.yml / configuration.yml at Bitnami Redmine?

Tags: redmine, password-encryption, bitnami

I'm a newbie on REDMINE(my version is 1.4.4)

I just got a question that is there any way that I can encrypt my email password on configuration.yml file which is to set up email configuration.

FYI, current setting is like below.

```
email_delivery:
    delivery_method: :smtp
    smtp_settings:
      tls: true
      address: smtp.gmail.com
      port: 587
      domain: smtp.gmail.com
      authentication: :plain
      user_name: "myEmailAddress@gmail.com"
      password: "myEmailPassword"     # I don't want to reveal my pw here :(
      enable_starttls_auto: true
```

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can but the only way I know to do it is to install and use Postfix as the relay and setup stunnel to handle the encrypted password exchange.

I had my system setup that way for a while but now I use Postfix without stunnel because Amazon SES service now supports starttls.

I had help from this site in my original setup:
http://quietmint.com/linux/postfix-relaying-mail-through-an-smtps-smarthost-on-port-465/

My latest setup I derived help from here:
http://blog.duoconsulting.com/2012/01/30/using-amazons-ses-with-postfix-as-a-smarthost-forwarder/